# Combinations of k elements from n groups with one element per group at most.

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to compute how many unordered triplets I can get from $\mathbf{n}$ groups with $\mathbf{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n}$ items respectively taking at most one item per group.

For example imagine I have 4 groups of colors A, B, C and D. For color A, I have $x_1$ shades that I will represent as $|A|=x_1$, in the same way $|B|=x_2$, $|C|=x_3$ and $|D|=x_4$. In this case a "brute force" calculation allows to get $$Total = x_1 x_2 x_3 + x_1 x_2 x_4 + x_1 x_3 x_4 + x_2 x_3 x_4$$ the logic behind this case is to recreate all possibles combinations of 3 colors and multiply its shades. When group count increase the calculation gets complicated. But looks like for this particular case we can use the following calculation no matter the number of colors and number of shades in each one,lets define:

$s_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

$s_2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$

$s_3 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3$

$$Total = \frac{s_1^3+2s_3-3s_1s_2}{6}$$

So my questions are:

1. Why $Total = \frac{s_1^3+2s_3-3s_1s_2}{6}$ works?
2. Is there a way to generalize this procedure for differents values of k and n groups?, I mean instead of triplets calculate the same for quads with more groups. We can assume $n\ge{k}$

For ex: $|A|=x_1=1, |B|=x_2=2, |C|=x_3=3, |D|=x_4=4$

**Brute Force Approach**
$$Total = x_1 x_2 x_3 + x_1 x_2 x_4 + x_1 x_3 x_4 + x_2 x_3 x_4=1*2*3+1*2*4+1*3*4+2*3*4=50$$

**Mysterious Approach**

$s_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1+2+3+4=10$

$s_2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=1+4+9+16=30$

$s_3 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3=1+8+27+64=100$

$$Total = \frac{s_1^3+2s_3-3s_1s_2}{6} = \frac{10^3+2*100-3*10*30}{6}=50$$

Comment: As a sanity check, consider the case where $x_i=x$ for all $i$.  It is plain to see the total should have been $\binom{n}{3}x^3$ in such a case.  Your proposed formula gives $\dfrac{(nx)^3+2n(x^3)-3(nx)(nx^2)}{6}=\dfrac{n^3-3n^2+2n}{6}x^3=\binom{n}{3}x^3$, so it at least passes initial speculation.

Comment: I'm not as strong with algebra any more as I once was, but a line of inquiry that could be fruitful is looking for further information on [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).  The summation you have here, $x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4$ and generalized to higher $n$ is precisely the elementary symmetric polynomial $e_3(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$.

Comment: After a little digging, it seems you have stumbled upon one of [Newton's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks a lot for your answer, I am trying to ingest symmetric polynomials and Newton's identities. I was expecting that the reason behind the question relies more on combinatoric logic